# What is the requirement for a Page Viewer Web Part?

Tags: 2010, web-part, page-viewer-web-part

I've been running a number of Page Viewer Web Parts on my development environment, but upon deploying the system to a production environment I find that there's no Media and Content catalogue, and there's no Page Viewer Web Part available.

What do I need to install or configure to allow this type of Web Part to be added to a page?

Comment: a way to find the answer, on the dev box, run a `Get-SPFeature -Url http://localhost`. Do the same on the target box, diff the activated features, and try to activate the feature until the webpart is present.

Answer (score 1):

This webpart is provided with the feature "BasicWebParts" (ID: 00BFEA71-1C5E-4A24-B310-BA51C3EB7A57).

It's a hidden feature, activated by the out-of-the-box site template. See

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\MPS\XML\onet.xml

for example.

In your case, are use using a custom site definition ? If yes, add this feature to your onet.xml (you should do the same for all features of a blank site, aka STS#1).

If not, you can try to add it using a simple :

```
Enable-SPFeature -identity 00BFEA71-1C5E-4A24-B310-BA51C3EB7A57 -Url http://localhost
```

But you should really wonder why this feature is not activated... maybe your site is messed up and creating a new one can be a good idea (if you can...).

Comment: I don't have any control over the site, but I need to know what I need to request from the administrators. I've never seen an installation that didn't allow a Page Viewer Web Page and was really surprised.